# How would you model a collection of users and friends in Firebase?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm trying to create a database (json) with Firebase.
I searched the docs and the net but couldn't find a clear way to start.
I want to have a database of users.
each user (represented as UID) should have a nickname and a list of friends.

I tried making a .json file that looks like this:

```
{
  users:{

  }
}
```

and adding it to the Firebase console to get started but it wouldn't work.
How can I do it?

the database should look like this:

```
{
  users:{
       UID:{
          nickname: hello
          friends: UID2
       }
       UID2:{
          nickname: world
          friends: UID
  }
}
```

I don't know if I got that right, so I would really appreciate any help you guys could give me at this subject.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like a good place to start. I would make two changes though.

1. keep the list is friends separate
2. keep the friends as a set, instead of a single value or array

#### keep the list is friends separate

A basic recommendation when using the Firebase Database is to keep your data structure shallow/flat. There are many reasons for this, and you have at least two.

1. With your current data structure, say that you want to show a list of user names. You can only get that list by listening to `/users`. And that means you don't just get the user name for each user, but also their list of friends. Chances that you're going to show all that data to the user are minimal, so that means that you've just wasted some of their bandwidth.
2. Say that you want to allow everyone to read the list of user names. But you only want each user to be able to read their own list of friends. Your current data structure makes that hard, since [permission cascades](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade) and [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters).

A better structure is to keep the list of user profiles (currently just their name) separate from the list of friends for each user.

#### keep the friends as a set

You current have just a single value for the `friends` property. As you start building the app you will need to store multiple friends. The most common is to then store an array or list of UIDS:

```
[ UID1, UID2, UID3 ]
```

Or

```
{
  "-K.......1": "UID1"
  "-K.......5": "UID2"
  "-K.......9": "UID3"
}
```

These are unfortunately the wrong type for this data structure. Both the array and the second collection are lists: an ordered collection of (potentially) non-unique values. But a collection of friends doesn't have to be ordered, it *has* to be unique. I'm either in the collection or I'm not in there, I can't be in there multiple times and the order typically doesn't matter. That's why you often end up looking for `friends.contains("UID1")` or `ref.orderByValue().equalTo("UID1")` operations with the above models.

A much better model is to store the data as a set. A set is a collection of unordered values, which have to be unique. Perfect for a collection of friends. To store that in Firebase, we use the UID as the key of the collection. And since we can't store a key without a value, we use `true` as the dummy value.

So this leads to this data model:

```
{
  users:{
     UID:{
       nickname: hello
     }
     UID2:{
       nickname: world
     }
  }
  friends:{
     UID:{
       UID2: true
     }
     UID2:{
       UID: true
     }
  }
}
```

There is a lot more to say/learn about NoSQL data modeling in general and Firebase specifically. To learn about that, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: Thank you very much! Really helped me to understand things better!

Comment: This works, but if you need to get the friends of friends, or get the friends that are older than 18 you will have to resort to other solutions. Maybe a third party server, filtering in the client, or using cloud functions.

In any case once you need those kind of relationships and queries you have probably outgrown a DB like Firebase (or Mongo for that matter).

Comment: @SebastianDenis he explained it _**And that means you don't just get the user name for each user, but also their list of friends**_. If some users have lets say as much as 200 friends and in one of your views (for example Users table view in administrator pages), in your structure you'll get **a lot of** unnecessary data just while querying users list.

Comment: @Frank What if I have to show nicknames of all the friends of a specific user? Should I fetch nicknames of all the users and filter on client side? Or should I query for each friend?

Answer (score 0):

I keep a collection of `Friends` where the `users` field is an array of 2 user ids: `['user1', 'user2']`.

Getting the friends of a user is easy:

```
friendsCollection.where("users", "array-contains", "user1").get()
```

This should get you all documents where user1 appears.

Now the tricky part was on how to query a single friend. Ideally, firebase would support multiple values in `array-contains`, but they won't do that: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1169

So they way I get around this is to normalize the `users` list before adding the document. Basically I'm utilizing JS' truthiness to check what `userId` is greater, and which is smaller, and then making a list in that order.

when adding a friend:

```
const user1 = sentBy > sentTo ? sentBy : sentTo
const user2 = sentBy > sentTo ? sentTo : sentBy

const friends = { users: [user1, user2] }

await friendsCollection.add(friends)
```

This basically ensures that whoever is part of the friendship will always be listed in the same order, so when querying, you can just:

```
await friendsCollection.where("users", "==", [user1, user2]).get()
```

This obviously only works because I trust the list will always have 2 items, and trust that the JS truthiness will work deterministically, but it's a great solution *for this specific problem.*