# NoSQL Database Structure for Facebook type social network

Tags: database, mongodb, firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

For a Facebook type social networking app, a high performing database structure is required, for storing data in Firebase(Cloud Firestore) (NoSQL).

Data to be stored :

```
 - Userinfo (name, email etc)
 - Friends
 - Posts
 - Comments on posts.
```

I am confused among the following two DB Structures regarding query performance (if the database becomes huge).

*(Ref: C_xxx is Collection, D_xxx is document)*

**Structure 1**

```
C_AllData
    - D_UserID-1
        name: xxxx,
        email: yyy,
        friends: [UserID-3, UserID-4]
        - C_Posts
            - D_PostId-1
                Text: hhh
                Date: zzz
                - C_Comments
                    - D_CommentId-1
                        UserID: 3
                        Text: kkk
                    - D_CommentId-2
                        UserID: 4
                        Text: kkk
            - D_PostId-2
                Text: hhh
                Date: zzz
                - C_Comments
                    - D_CommentId-3
                        UserID: 3
                        Text: kkk
                    - D_CommentId-4
                        UserID: 4
                        Text: kkk
    - D_UserID-2
        name: xxxx,
        email: yyy
        friends: [UserID-5, UserID-7]
        - C_Posts
            - D_PostId-3
                Text: hhh
                Date: zzz
                - C_Comments
                    - D_CommentId-5
                        UserID: 5
                        Text: kkk
                    - D_CommentId-6
                        UserID: 7
                        Text: kkk
```

**Structure 2**

```
C_AllUsers 
    - D_UserID-1
        name: xxxx,
        email: yyy
        friends: [UserID-3, UserID-4]
    - D_UserID-2
        name: xxxx,
        email: yyy
        friends: [UserID-5, UserID-7]

C_AllPosts
    - D_PostId-1
        UserID: 1
        Text: hhh
        Date: zzz
        - C_Comments
            - D_CommentId-1
                UserID: 3
                Text: kkk
            - D_CommentId-2
                UserID: 4
                Text: kkk
    - D_PostId-3
        UserID: 2
        Text: hhh
        Date: zzz
        - C_Comments
            - D_CommentId-5
                UserID: 5
                Text: kkk
            - D_CommentId-6
                UserID: 7
                Text: kkk
```

**My Question is what are the pros and cons of the two approaches ?**

Some points that i could think of are below, please correct me if i am wrong.

**Structure 1 :**

Is getting all the posts of a given user, Faster in Structure 1 ? Since we are pinpointing to the exact collection ( AllData/{UserID}/Posts/ )

Since entire DB is under one collection, is scalability not good ?

**Structure 2 :**

Divided DB -> Better Scalability ?

Divided DB -> Better Performance ?

Lesser Nesting -> Better Performance ?

AllPosts under one collection -> Slow querying ?

---

Or if you can suggest a better model, that would be great too.

Comment: Hey in the end what worked best for you? Would you mind posting the data structure? It will be really helful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Firebase a rule of thumb is to keep separate entity types in separate branches. This is especially important because:

(Note: Here firebase is firebase realtime database)

1. Firebase always loads complete nodes, and
2. once you grant a user read access to a node, they have access to all data under that node.

For example in your first data structure, to load a list of friends, you will have to load all the posts of all friends, and all comments on all those posts too. That's a lot more data than is strictly needed, if all you wanted to do was show a list of the friends names.

In your second data structure, you are one step closer. As now you can first load the friends names, and then load their posts.

But even in that structure you have the same problem. If you want to display the list of post titles for a friend (or for all friends), you are going to have to load the entire posts and all comments. That is again way more data than is needed to show a list of post titles. So you'll definitely want to store the comments in a separate top-level list too, using the same key of the post to identify and group them.

```
C_AllPosts
    - D_PostId-1
        UserID: 1
        Text: hhh
        Date: zzz
    - D_PostId-3
        UserID: 2
        Text: hhh
        Date: zzz
C_AllComments
    - D_PostId-1
        - D_CommentId-1
            UserID: 3
            Text: kkk
        - D_CommentId-2
            UserID: 4
            Text: kkk
    - D_PostId-3
        - D_CommentId-5
            UserID: 5
            Text: kkk
        - D_CommentId-6
            UserID: 7
            Text: kkk
```

Now if you want to display a post and its comments, you will have to read two nodes. If you do this for multiple posts, you'll end up with a lot of reads, to essentially perform the NoSQL equivalent of a SQL `JOIN`. This is quite normal, it's essentially a client-side join, and it not nearly as slow as you may think, because [Firebase pipelines the requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786).

For some more introduction on this type of data modeling, I recommend:

- this article on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)
- the Firebase blog post [Denormalization is normal](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html)
- this video series [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s)

And these answers to previous questions:

- [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase)
- [How would you model a collection of users and friends in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973985/how-would-you-model-a-collection-of-users-and-friends-in-firebase/44974788#44974788)
- [Firebase data structure and url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638660/firebase-data-structure-and-url/16651115#16651115)
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16421179/whats-the-best-way-of-structuring-data-on-firebase/16423051?s=2|19.0394#16423051](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16421179/whats-the-best-way-of-structuring-data-on-firebase/16423051?s=2%7C19.0394#16423051)
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693785/how-to-write-denormalized-data-in-firebase/30699277?s=3|18.5624#30699277](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693785/how-to-write-denormalized-data-in-firebase/30699277?s=3%7C18.5624#30699277)
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830610/how-to-denormalize-normalize-data-structure-for-firebase-realtime-database/43832677?s=5|16.2022#43832677](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830610/how-to-denormalize-normalize-data-structure-for-firebase-realtime-database/43832677?s=5%7C16.2022#43832677)

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time to give a detailed answer. Now i have a better understanding of Firebase and DB structuring.

Comment: Frank, you mentioned that Firebase always loads entire nodes, but this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46875966/firestore-get-all-docs-and-subcollections-of-root-collection), it says that firebase does not load subcollections !! So in my question, in structure 1, if i read /C_AllData/<D_UserID-1> it will not give me anything under C_Posts since its a subcollection, and i need to query it again. So does firebase loads entire node or not ?

Comment: Also, when I said "Firebase" in my question, I wanted to say Firebase Cloud Firestore, not the Realtime DB. Data Structuring approaches among these two are different ?

Comment: Hey kernelman. My answer was indeed based on Realtime Database, I must've overlooked the Firestore tag and mention of collections. Sorry for the confusion. While many of the same principles apply to Cloud Firestore, there are some key differences. The automatic loading of subcollections is one of the bigger ones. In that case, a reason for moving all comments into a single collection is if you have a use-case to query over the comments on all posts. Since Firestore doesn't (yet) support querying across multiple collections, this use-case would require having all comments in a single collection

Comment: There is no performance difference though. One of the performance guarantees of Firestore is that the size of a collection has no impact on performance of queries against that collection.