# Firebase relational entity

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Hi I have a doubt about firebase relational entities,
In my case, I want to make a database for users and users can create a team.
In the team entity, team creators can add more users to join. Also can remove users from the team.

Can you share your experience or something to read about this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is an incredibly broad topic, so it'll be hard to succinctly help. The best I can do without more details, is give you some resources where to learn more:

- Firebase's documentation on [structuring data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data).
- [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), an article on general NoSQL data modeling techniques.
- [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s), a video series specifically for developers coming from a relational background.
- [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video), a video series for Firestore (another NoSQL database from Firebase) but much of the general advice also applies to the Realtime Database.
- These classic blogposts about [duplicating data](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html), and [Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

And I'd also recommend some of these questions on Stack Overflow:

- [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)
- [How to write denormalized data in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693785/how-to-write-denormalized-data-in-firebase/30699277#30699277)
- [How to denormalize/normalize data structure for firebase realtime database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830610/how-to-denormalize-normalize-data-structure-for-firebase-realtime-database/43832677#43832677)
- [How would you model a collection of users and friends in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973985/how-would-you-model-a-collection-of-users-and-friends-in-firebase/44974788#44974788)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the relational like this:

```
-user
   -userUid
       -allStuff
       -type
-team
   -teamUid
      -teamName
      -teamLeader
-teamMember
   -teamUid
      -userUid
      -userUid2
```

As you can see here, when team leader refer to `type` = `leader` . So this user can create other user. I hope you can understand this relation.